# How can I create a NSGradient from an array of colors and floats?

Tags: swift, tuples, variadic-functions, objective-c-swift-bridge, nsgradient

I have an array of `NSColor`s, and an array of `CGFloat`s signifying gradient stops. I can't figure out how to use these arrays to initialize a `NSGradient`.

I tried making these into an array of `(NSColor, CGFloat)`s, but `NSGradient(colorsAndLocations:` won't take it, since it expects varargs:

[image: The code <code>let gradient = NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: colorsAndLocations)</code> yielding the error <code>Cannot convert value of type '[(NSColor, CGFloat)]' to expected argument type '(NSColor, CGFloat)'</code>]

And `NSGradient(colors:, atLocations:, colorSpace:)` expects a `UnsafePointer` which I have no idea how to properly handle in Swift, if there is even such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know this usage:

```
let cAndL: [(NSColor, CGFloat)] = [(NSColor.redColor(), 0.0), (NSColor.greenColor(), 1.0)]
let gradient = NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: cAndL[0], cAndL[1])
```

Unfortunately, Swift does not provide us a way to give Arrays to variadic functions.

---

And the second portion. If some API claims `UnsafePointer<T>` as an array, you can create a Swift Array of T, and pass it directly to the API.

```
let colors = [NSColor.redColor(), NSColor.greenColor()]
let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
let gradient2 = NSGradient(colors: colors, atLocations: locations, colorSpace: NSColorSpace.genericRGBColorSpace())
```

If you want to utilize an `Array` of (`NSColor`, `CGFloat`), you can write something like this:

```
let gradient3 = NSGradient(colors: cAndL.map{$0.0}, atLocations: cAndL.map{$0.1}, colorSpace: NSColorSpace.genericRGBColorSpace())
```

Comment: _"you can create a Swift Array of T, and pass it directly to the API"_ Is this guaranteed to be safe?

Comment: @BenLeggiero, surely. See the Constant Pointers part of [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23).